# Low-res coastline of world landmass, in xml format?

Tags: data, xml

Can anyone direct me towards an xml file, in typical OSM format, for the low-res coastal Ways of every land-mass on Earth?

I need something easily renderable at low zoom levels, avoiding the superfluous detail of full-res data.

Comment: OSM coastlines are here: http://openstreetmapdata.com/data/coastlines but I don't know how to get them as XML without converting them first...

Comment: Why do you need OSM XML format? Most renderers can handle shapefiles as well. Natural Earth has low-res coastlines.

Comment: Because I am using my own custom renderer, which only has the capacity to parse OSM XML format.